# Generation of table and accessing elements of a Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, hash

I have the following Array of hashes in a rails application:

```
a = ["{\"ROW1\"=>{\"correct\"=>{\"h\"=>\"10\", \"m\"=>\"11\", \"l\"=>
\"12\"}, \"wrong\"=>{\"h\"=>\"2\", \"m\"=>\"2\", \"l\"=>\"4\"}, \"blank
\"=>{\"h\"=>\"2\", \"m\"=>\"4\", \"l\"=>\"3\"}}, \"ROW2\"=>{\"correct
\"=>{\"h\"=>\"2\", \"m\"=>\"4\", \"l\"=>\"4\"}, \"wrong\"=>{\"h
\"=>\"4\", \"m\"=>\"6\", \"l\"=>\"6\"}, \"blank\"=>{\"h\"=>\"7\", 
\"m\"=>\"5\", \"l\"=>\"6\"}}, \"ROW3\"=>{\"correct\"=>{\"h\"=>\"4\", 
\"m\"=>\"6\", \"l\"=>\"7\"}, \"wrong\"=>{\"h\"=>\"6\", \"m\"=>\"7\", 
\"l\"=>\"5\"}, \"blank\"=>{\"h\"=>\"7\", \"m\"=>\"9\", \"l\"=>
\"3\"}}}"]
```

I want to access its elements and create a database table from it, in the following format

```
ROW1          correct    h=10, m=11,l=12
              wrong      h=2, m=2,l=4
              blank      h=2, m=4,l=3
```

...and similar for ROW2 and ROW3.

How can I do that?

I tried to access a value using

```
a["ROW1"]["Correct"]["h"]
```

...but it returns a nil value.

How to access the values of this array of hashes?

Comment: How did you generate the string? That's not a valid Ruby hash, nor is it JSON and looks like you are doing something wrong in its generation. (See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)). When asking about a problem with your code we need to see your effort. Read "[mcve]" for what we need.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer, (only) if you think it is the correct solution. It will help other viewers also to know the credibility of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to first convert the string to hash which can be done as follows:

```
require 'json'

a = ["{\"ROW1\"=>{\"correct\"=>{\"h\"=>\"10\", \"m\"=>\"11\", \"l\"=>
\"12\"}, \"wrong\"=>{\"h\"=>\"2\", \"m\"=>\"2\", \"l\"=>\"4\"}, \"blank
\"=>{\"h\"=>\"2\", \"m\"=>\"4\", \"l\"=>\"3\"}}, \"ROW2\"=>{\"correct
\"=>{\"h\"=>\"2\", \"m\"=>\"4\", \"l\"=>\"4\"}, \"wrong\"=>{\"h
\"=>\"4\", \"m\"=>\"6\", \"l\"=>\"6\"}, \"blank\"=>{\"h\"=>\"7\", 
\"m\"=>\"5\", \"l\"=>\"6\"}}, \"ROW3\"=>{\"correct\"=>{\"h\"=>\"4\", 
\"m\"=>\"6\", \"l\"=>\"7\"}, \"wrong\"=>{\"h\"=>\"6\", \"m\"=>\"7\", 
\"l\"=>\"5\"}, \"blank\"=>{\"h\"=>\"7\", \"m\"=>\"9\", \"l\"=>
\"3\"}}}"
]

hash_string = a[0]
hash = JSON.parse hash_string.gsub("\n", '').gsub('=>', ':')

# you access the hash now:
hash["ROW1"]["correct"]["h"]
# => 10
```

Btw, please note that there is a typo. Instead of `Correct`, the key is `correct` with small `c` instead of capital `C`.

Hope it helps : )

Comment: The first thing is to understand _why_ the hash is in a string, not convert it. Once the hash is being represented correctly then we can move forward.